# Javascript array splice in animation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently working on a map generator in canvas.

Here is the code working code : http://jsfiddle.net/RtPmm/

and the piece that raise an issue :

```
MapBuilder = function(){
...
this.checkPath = function(){
...
(logic condition ...)    {
  var i = Game.builders.indexOf(this);
  Game.builders.splice(i,1); /!\
}
```

and in the render function :

```
for (var i = 0, len = Game.builders.length; i < len; i++) {
  Game.builders[i].checkPath();
}
```

My problem is that when my MapBuilder objects are supposed to be remove from the array, the animateloop function still find deleted index when it iterate throughGame.builders array.

I can't really find this out..

Thanks for taking the time to leave an answer (or comment)

Comment: have you tried `delete Game.builders[i]`?

Comment: Using delete is a bad practice and won't work here

Comment: Why is `delete` bad practice?

Comment: It won't remove an element from an array it will only set it as undefined, which will then not be reflected correctly in the length of the array.

Comment: It can find the index but the item would be deleted. For example, [1, 2, 3, 4], if I remove the item at index 1, after splicing, 3 will be in index 1.

Comment: You are right, thanks for enlighten me @Itay :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's because you are looping until the initial length of the array is reached, but the length changes as you remove items and the items gets shifted.

There are several solutions to this problem, like looping backward instead, or something like:

```
var builders = Game.builders,
    builder;
for (var i = 0, len = builders.length; i < len; i++) {
   (builder = builders[i]).checkPath();
   if (builders[i] !== builder) {
       //builder was removed, fix the loop
       --i; --len;
   }
}
```